# Maven repository server for caching

Tags: maven, server, repository, local

I'm trying to understand some concepts about maven. This is the my scenario:
Almost every time I deploy a project, i.e Cloudstack I type:

```
mvn install
```

I got some failures like unable to connect to some repositories or that some tests just failed. I don't understand why some tests can fail if the code has been recently downloaded.

My idea is to create a local server repository so maven won't connect to remote servers but to a server that is in the same network with the packages that the application needs.

Is possible to do that? or does these problems are produced by other cause?

Comment: Can you post some of the errors you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Maven, Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html):

> There are strictly only two types of repositories: local and remote. The local repository refers to a copy on your own installation that is a cache of the remote downloads, and also contains the temporary build artifacts that you have not yet released.
>
> Remote repositories refer to any other type of repository, [...]. These repositories might be a truly remote repository set up by a third party to provide their artifacts for downloading [...]. Other "remote" repositories may be internal repositories set up on a file or HTTP server within your company, used to share private artifacts between development teams and for releases.

`mvn install` does *not deploy* your project's artifact (at least not in the sense of Maven's `deploy`, see [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)). It does:

> install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally

whereas `mvn deploy` is:

> done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects

„*unable to connect to some repositories*“ and „*some tests just failed*“ are two different kind of errors. It's impossible to tell more without any relevant part(s) of the output of the build where these occurred.